# Hiding/Deactivating "Demote" button on Ideas

Tags: visualforce, customization, button, ideas

I'm looking to implement "Ideas" in an organisation, but they have concerns as to having a "Demote" button being against the spirit of the initiative.

There doesn't seem to be any good options for getting rid of the buttons or the down votes. I can query down votes only after I specify the ID of the Idea, so it can't be caught on creation and there's no customization available for turning off the button. Anyone have any ideas?

Edit: This was an older question, but I was looking for solutions outside of hacking the side bar, it was the worst possible solution and I HATED implementing it. I would not consider this question a duplicate. It just didn't have an answer at the time and I hate seeing unresolved questions. Just because fending off zombies and banging in a nail both require a hammer doesn't mean the problem is the same.

Comment: Love the analogy......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was initially resolved with a javascript sidebar hack, it's not a clean solution but worked. Was broken by recent updates, so I won't link to the articles. It currently seems impossible.

Answer (score -2):

You can use this styles in your VF page

.voteButton a.voteDown {
display: none;
}

Comment: Surendra, this isn't an answer to the question. Did you read the part of the OP's post where this is a standard page that can't be customized to add code to the buttons?